# WPF listbox IsChecked property

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have problem with property binding. It does not work.

```
<Window x:Class="ProblemWithScrolling.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Test}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Check}"></CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Label Height="40" Width="200" Content="Test"></Label>
</StackPanel>
```

**Code behind**                                                             *

```
namespace ProblemWithScrolling
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<DataStruct> test;
    public List<DataStruct> Test
    {
        get { return test; }
        set { test = value; }
    }
    public string check;
    public string Check
    {
        get { return check; }
        set { check = value; if (value == "True") { Debug.WriteLine(this.Name); }
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Test = new List<DataStruct>();
        Test.Add(new DataStruct { Name = "First", Number = "2" });
        Test.Add(new DataStruct { Name = "Second", Number = "2" });
        Test.Add(new DataStruct { Name = "Third", Number = "2" });
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}

public class DataStruct
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

}

Is it possible to bind `IsChecked` property to Check property. I understand that it is trying to find Check property into `DataStruct`.

Comment: what is `this.Name` in `MainWindow`? Move `Check`property in `DataStruct` !

Answer (score 1):

1. Your property needs to be a bool.
2. Your property needs to implement a proper `INotifyPropertyChanged` handling.
3. Your property needs to be a property of the data context.

*OR*

3. Your Binding needs to access another data context.

You can use [this handy cheat sheet](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/WpfBinding.pdf) to look up any weird binding you may need in the future.

Comment: 1. It's no matter what it would get "True" or "true".
2. No need to update UI.
3. Check is in the datacontext, but it does not work.

Comment: Your datacontext for each container element switched to a single item of the underlying list (or you would not be able to bind to Name). So you need to access your original datacontext. There are different ways, relative bindings, giving a name or something else. Pick the one you prefer.

Comment: I prefer relative binding

Answer (score 0):

You haven't `this.Name` `MainWindow`. Move the `Check` property in `DataStruct`. It's a good thing to put this property as a `Boolean`.

```
public class DataStruct
{
    public Boolean check;

    public Boolean Check
    {
        get { return check; }
        set
        {
            check = value;
            if (value) { Debug.WriteLine(this.Name); }
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

In `MainWindow`, you can use it :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<DataStruct> test;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Test = new List<DataStruct>();
        Test.Add(new DataStruct { Name = "First", Number = "2", Check = true });
        Test.Add(new DataStruct { Name = "Second", Number = "2" });
        Test.Add(new DataStruct { Name = "Third", Number = "2" });
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public List<DataStruct> Test
    {
        get { return test; }
        set { test = value; }
    }
}
```